# Concourse docker web component fails to run

Tags: concourse

I am trying to run Concourse from the 3.5.0 docker image and using the docker-compose.yml example as a template.
I created a bridged docker network for the connections then started the postgres docker container created keys in directories web and worker.
The web one contains;

```
authorised_worker_keys (which is the public key worker_key.pub) 
session_signing_key                               
session_signing_key.pub 
tsa_host_key 
tsa_host_key.pub
```

The worker one contains;

```
tsa_host_key.pub worker_key worker_key.pub
```

Then started a web instance in the same docker network with;

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 \
-e "CONCOURSE_EXTERNAL_URL=http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080" \
-e "CONCOURSE_BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME=concourse" \
-e "CONCOURSE_BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD=changeme" \
-e "CONCOURSE_POSTGRES_HOST=concourse-db" \
-e "CONCOURSE_POSTGRES_USER=concourse" \
-e "CONCOURSE_POSTGRES_PASSWORD=changeme" \
-e "CONCOURSE_POSTGRES_DATABASE=concourse" \
--name=concourse-web \
--net=concourse_network \
-v web:/concourse-keys \
concourse/concourse web
```

This web container fails and logs

```
failed to load authorised keys: open : no such file or directory
```

If I exec a shell in the postgres container and login using psql I can see that the database has had some tables added for concourse so that connection must have worked.

A worker container starts and stays running when I start it with;

```
docker run -d \
--name=concourse-worker-1 \
--privileged \
--net=concourse_network \
-v worker:/concourse-keys
-e "CONCOURSE_TSA_HOST=concourse-web" \
concourse/concourse worker
```

Has anyone any ideas what is causing the "failed to load authorized keys" message and how I can beat it please?
If I run it from docker compose on my laptop is works perfectly but I can't run docker compose in our environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have spotted the issue and corrected it this morning so I'll post it here for others to learn from my stupidity. BTW I worked it out my comparing docker inspect outputs from the containers started from the docker-compose file and mine in the other environment.

The mounts needed a full path not a relative path i.e.

```
-v /home/concourse/keys/web:/concourse-keys
```

and

```
-v /home/concourse/keys/worker:/concourse-keys
```

Thanks for reading.